# How to combine REST API outputs to a single variable

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I've a api which will execute on different hosts and get data.But to do some if conditions it taking only single host values instaed all host values.
Example:
host1 output:

```
{'records': [{'node': '2551a', 'name': 'Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 40}, {'node': '1a','name': 'Out Flow Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 52}, {'node': '255rtp-1b', 'name': 'CPU0 Temp Margin', 'units': 'C', 'value': 25}],'num_records': 3}
```

host2 output:

```
{'records': [{'node': '700f', 'name': 'Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 28}, {'node': '1a','name': 'Temp3', 'units': 'C', 'value': 30}, {'node': '700rtp-1b', 'name': 'Temp Margin', 'units': 'C', 'value': 25}],'num_records': 3}
```

In this json data wanted to print if the value beyond 20.

My code is:

```
for cluster in clusters_list:
    api_endpoint = f"https://{host}/api/private/

    try:
        response = requests.request(method='GET', url=api_endpoint, **kwargs)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as error:
        print("Failed with error: {}.".format(error))
        return

    if response:
        rc = response.status_code
        data = response.json()
    #new_records = [record for record in data['records'] if record['value'] > 25]
    new_records = [record for record in data['records'] if 'value' in record and record['value'] > 20]
    records_beyond = {'records': new_records, 'num_records': len(new_records)}
print("sorted records",records_beyond)
```

output will be host2 data:

```
{'records': [{'node': '700f', 'name': 'Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 28}, {'node': '1a','name': 'Temp3', 'units': 'C', 'value': 30}, {'node': '700rtp-1b', 'name': 'Temp Margin', 'units': 'C', 'value': 25}],'num_records': 3}
```

How to save collected data and print all hosts data?

Answer (score 0):

create a new variable and append to it.

```
all_records = []

for cluster in clusters_list:
    api_endpoint = f"https://{host}/api/private/

    try:
        response = requests.request(method='GET', url=api_endpoint, **kwargs)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as error:
        print("Failed with error: {}.".format(error))
        return

    if response:
        rc = response.status_code
        data = response.json()
    #new_records = [record for record in data['records'] if record['value'] > 25]
    new_records = [record for record in data['records'] if 'value' in record and record['value'] > 20]
    records_beyond = {'records': new_records, 'num_records': len(new_records)}
    all_records.append(records_beyond)
print("all records",all_records)
```

This will print all the records

output will be:

```
all records [{'records': [{'node': '2a', 'name': 'Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 20}, {'node': 'tp-2b', 'name': 'Bat Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 28}], 'num_records': 2}, {'records': [{'node': 'rtp-1a', 'name': 'In Flow Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 39},  {'node': '1a', 'name': 'Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 39},  {'node': 'rtp-1b', 'name': 'Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 45}, {'node': '1b', 'name': 'Temp', 'units': 'C', 'value': 45}], 'num_records': 5}]
```